# stored procedure not getting parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Hi I have a stored procedure and a connection to the database. I have other similar code on my website that works just fine but for the life of me I cannot get this to work. I want the username of the person logged in to be passed as a parameter. I can get it stored in a session variable. 
I wasnt sure how to transfer it from the session variable to the parameter so I put it into a label and sent it that way. It shows that it is getting that far but everytime I just get the message 'nothing found' 
I have checked the stored procedure and that seems fine to me. Below is the code and stored procedure! please help!

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.UI;
        using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
        using System.Web.Security;
        using System.Data.SqlClient;
        using System.Configuration;
        using System.Data;

        public partial class RescueOnlyPages_EditRescueDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MembershipUser user;
                try
                {
                    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        // Set theme in preInit event
                        user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
                        Session["user"] = user;
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string msg = ex.Message;
                    //Log error here

                    // We have set theme in web.config to Neutral so if there is
                    // an error with setting themes, an incorrect theme wont be displayed to a customer

                }


            }
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                userLabel.Text = Session["user"].ToString();

                SqlDataReader myDataReader = default(SqlDataReader);

                SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RescueAnimalsIrelandConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_EditRescueDetails", MyConnection);    

                if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                }
                else 
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", userLabel.Text.Trim());

                }

                 try
               {
                MyConnection.Open();
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                myDataReader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                myDataReader.Read();


                GridViewED.DataSource = myDataReader;
                GridViewED.DataBind();

                if (GridViewED.Rows.Count >= 1)
                {

                    GridViewED.Visible = true;
                    lblMsg.Visible = false;           

                }
                else if (GridViewED.Rows.Count < 1)
                {
                    GridViewED.Visible = false;

                    lblMsg.Text = "Your search criteria returned no results.";
                    lblMsg.Visible = true;
                }





                MyConnection.Close();
               }
                 catch (SqlException SQLexc)
                 {
                     Response.Write("Read Failed : " + SQLexc.ToString());
                 }
            }


            }
```

stored procedure

```
 ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_EditRescueDetails]
(
   @user nvarchar(50)

 )
 AS
 BEGIN


 SELECT [PostalAddress], [Telephone_No], [Website], [Email] 
 FROM [RescueDetails] 
 Where   [UserName] = @user 
 End
```

EDIT *****
If I change the stored procedure and delete the 
       ' Where   [UserName] = @user ' 
line it brings in every user detail without any problem so I think it maybe something with this line or the 
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", userLabel.Text.Trim()); 
line that is causing me the problems

Comment: Please please please put your `MyConnection.Close()` call in a `finally` block - better still, wrap the connection in a `using` statement. :) Other than that, could you step through your code in the debugger and make sure that a value is definitely getting added to the parameters? Also - you don't need to use a label to store the user, you should use a [local variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664742%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: yes i have the finally block in the other pieces of code but I have been deleting and changing this code to try and get it working. Any ideas of whats wrong?? Its driving me mad!

Comment: @David Neale i added it to the label to see if that would help. I have stepped through it and the correct username shows up atthe line 'command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", userLabel.Text.Trim());' on the userLabel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

before

```
 MyConnection.Open();
```

Also don't call  `myDataReader.Read();` if you are going to set the `myDataReader` as the data source for gridview. That will make it skip a row and if result has only one row then the grid will display nothing.

Comment: no it still comes up with "Your search criteria returned no results." And I have added data to the database for that user so it def should be showing up.

Comment: @mar84 I edited my answer a little bit. Are you skipping the `Read()` call ?

Comment: Thank you soo sooo much!! Yes it was the myDataReader.Read(); line that was wrong. I dont know if I ever would have spotted it. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

When adding command parameters of text type (varchar, nvarchar) ADO.NET  works best when you supply the length of the text value.
Try adding the parameter and then setting the length property and then assigning the value property, rather than using AddWithValue.